# Mvc c# coding in Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, but i am getting below error:

`Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.`

```
<div class="score" style="display: none;">
     @{
        int countCategory = 4;

        if (countCategory >= 2)
        {
           <div id="barScoreCategory-1" class="score-btn">
           <p>ABC1</p>
           </div>
           <div id="barScoreCategory-2" class="score-btn checkbox-blue">
           <p>ABC2</p>
           </div>
           if (countCategory >= 3)
           {
                <div id="barScoreCategory-3" class="score-btn checkbox-orange">
                <p>ABC3</p>
                </div>   
                if (countCategory == 4)
                {
                     <div id="barScoreCategory-4" class="score-btn checkbox-dark-gray">
                     <p>ABC4</p>
                     </div>
                 }
            }
         }
      }
</div>
```

Actual code block should be close after all if conditions close parenthesis but it actually closes before last parenthesis of last if condition.

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening on this view?

Comment: Yes when I remove this code its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry, It was mistake from my end but thanks for give hand to help me out.

Comment: Can you post the full exception

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272720/error-executing-child-request-for-handler-in-view