# Embed fully-fledged view + aynchronous controller in asp.net cshtml view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a cshtml controller with roughly the following logic:

```
public class MyController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string query){
         // do something with query and put result in 'myModel'
         return View(await myModel.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when I call the action directly.

Now I want a dashboard, which calls this controller action 3 times, each with different query parameters, approximately like this:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "myControllerName", new { query = "foo" })
@Html.Action("Index", "myControllerName", new { query = "bar" })
@Html.Action("Index", "myControllerName", new { query = "baz" })
```

The code throws an exception on the first `@Html` line though:

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: [*translated: error while executing*] handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Based on this question [Error executing child request for handler in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272720/error-executing-child-request-for-handler-in-view) I built a second method returning a partial view, and I checked if there was a [HttpGet] to remove (there wasn't). Neither works.

***edit*** building a partial view, which is not async, does work, based on pressing continue after the exception and Googling the error, and finding this question: [Async PartialView causes "HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked..." exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072720/async-partialview-causes-httpserverutility-execute-blocked-exception) . Not happy with the synchronous solution though, and still working on a viable solution

Comment: Are you calling these actions FROM a partial view?

Comment: No, from a 'regular' view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, async **child** actions are not supported in ASP.NET MVC 5. Support of async actions was introduced in ASP.NET Core MVC 6.

You can execute async code in your action with [AyncPump](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/26/35/55/AsyncPump.cs) from [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/02/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3/), but the action method must still be synchronous.

Comment: The full information + potential solution is much appreciated